# Let $A,B$ be square matrices $5\times 5$ and $\rho(B) > \rho(A)$ given the span of the solution space of $Ax=0$ prove $AB \not = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ be square matrices $5\times 5$ and $\rho(B) > \rho(A)$ $(\rho = rank)$ given the span of the solution space  $Sp\{(1,1,-1,5,2),(3,1,-2,8,1),(-1,1,0,2,3)\}$ of $Ax=0$ prove $AB \not = 0$

I want to solve this in two ways , one by contradiction and one by proofs

first way by contradiction:

let $\mbox{P(A)}=Sp\{(1,1,-1,5,2),(3,1,-2,8,1),(-1,1,0,2,3)\}$ the solution space of $Ax=0$ and assume that $\mbox{AB}=0$ then it means that for every $j$, $(1 \leq j \leq n)$ we have $[AB]_j^c=0$ therefore $[AB]_j^c=A[B]_j^c=0$ so every column of $B$ is a solution for $Ax=0$ so the column space $W$ of $B$ is in $P(A)$ which leads to $dimP(A) \geq dimW =\rho(B)$ then according to the dimension theorem $dimP(A)=5- \rho(A)$ so we get $\rho(B) \leq 5- \rho(A)$

now in order to find $dimP(A)$ we will sort the vectors of the span in a matrix

$$A= \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  1&1&-1&5&2\\
  0&2&-1&7&5\\
  0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

we will get that $\dim(P(A))=2$ which leads to $\rho(A)=3$ and $\rho(B) \leq 2$ which is not right according to the given information that $\rho(B) \gt\rho(A)$ so $AB \not=0$

for this proof I have only one questions , would it make a difference to write the vectors of the span as rows in the matrix or as columns? I find it confusing for when to write them as columns and when as rows..

The second way I tried (got stuck):

first I tried writing the vectors of the spans as a linear combination to check linear independence $\qquad$ $\alpha(1,1,-1,5,2)+ \beta(3,1,-2,8,1) +\gamma(-1,1,0,2,3)=0$ I put them in a matrix (as columns this time)

$$A= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&3&-1\\
  1&1&1\\
 -1&-2&0\\
  5&8&2 \\
  2&1&3\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and after doing the elimination process I got that $\gamma$ is a free variable so let $\gamma = t$ and we get $\alpha = -2t$ $\qquad$ $\beta =t$ $\qquad$ $\gamma =t$ and $\rho(A)=2$

so according to the dimension theorem $dimP(A)=n- \rho(A)$ we get $dimP(A)=5-2=3$ and I got stuck here

But if the matrix is like before (written as rows) I get $\rho(A)=3$ therefore $dim(P(A))=2$

and if $\rho(A)=3$ then $\rho(B) \geq 4$

so $\rho(AB) \leq min \{\rho(A), \rho(B)\}$ meaning $\rho(AB) \leq 3$ which is not zeros

I know the second way is not correct but am I getting to something there? it is more important to me to solve by a way that is not contradiction

thanks for any help and tips

Comment: You write $\rho(A)>\rho(B)$, but then you use $\rho(B)>\rho(A)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the correction ! edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: taking the vectors as the columns of a matrix and taking the vectors as the rows of a matrix are both valid approaches.

Your first proof is mostly correct. However, keep in mind that it does not make sense to refer to the matrix whose rows span $P(A)$ as "$A$", since that name is taken. If we refer to the matrix with these rows of $M$, then we can note as you did that the span of the rows of $M$ (which has dimension $\rho(M)$) is equal to $\dim P(A)$.

With this in mind, the issue with your second proof is a bit clearer. The matrix whose columns span $P(A)$ should not be referred to as "$A$". If we refer to this matrix as $M$, then we can make the analogous statement that the span of the **columns** of $M$ in this case is equal to $P(A)$, and this space has dimension equal to $\rho(M)$. It is not surprising that $\dim P(M) = 5 - 2 = 3$ is not equal to $\dim P(A)$.